# I am trying to run a non parametric ANCOVA in R but I am running into issues with the code and my understanding

Tags: r, ancova

I am looking at the concentration of a protein in two areas over time and want to determine if their regression slopes are significantly different. In both areas the concentration of the protein is increasing linearly over time, however, for one area the data is not normally distributed and for the other area it does not possess homogeneity. Therefore, I am trying to run a non-parametric ANCOVA using the sm.ancova function but keep getting the error:

```
Error in optimise(f = get(fname), interval = log(c(start/8, start * 4)),  : 
  invalid 'xmin' value
```

I setup the equation:

```
nonpm<- sm.ancova(Area1, Area2, Age,  model="parallel")
```

where Area1 and Area2 is the concentration of the protein in each area respectively.

The data is as follows:

```
Area1 <- c(19.3875, 44.689546, 39.43958333, 45.22222222, 57.15703125, 34.9421875, 32.6390625, 62.50298507, 60.5515625, 61.5140625, 72.221875, 48.778125) 

Area2 <- c(60.56111111, 62.536733, 75.42638889, 73.02777778, 144.340625, 42.0578125, 49.7578125, 79.37565399, 126.946875, 92.1765625, 130.521875, 125.7265625) 

Age <- c(119, 154, 174, 176, 183, 188, 190, 194, 230, 232, 245, 247)
```

Any help in both understanding the non-parametricc ANCOVA and the error here would be greatly appreciated. I am a newbie to non-parametricc analysis. Thanks!

I also tried using the loess.ancova but ran into similar problems

Comment: What are your grouping factor and response variable?

Comment: Response variable is Area2 and grouping variable is Age

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you evaluated the assumptions.  Did you evaluate the assumptions by looking at the residuals? The assumptions for the general linear model (regression, ANOVA, ANCOVA, etc.) are that the *residuals* are homogeneous, normal, independent (Eisenhart, 1947; Seber,  1966; Neter et al., 1983, pp. 31, 49; Quinn and Keogh, 2002, pp. 110, 280).

The `plot` function in R is an easy way to evaluate normal error assumptions:

```r
pMod <- lm(protein ~ age * area,  model = "parallel")
plot(pMod)
```

where `area` is the categorical variable (2 areas) and `age` is the regression variable.  The interaction term measures the difference in slopes.

Violations of the normal error assumptions can often be addressed with a generalized linear model, fitted using `glm()`.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks so much for your reply. To check my assumptions I ran them on individual linear models (Protein ~ Age for Area1 and Area2) but perhaps that is where I went wrong. I did run the linear model you mentioned above and checked the assumptions for that but still have a few questions. 
1) the combined pMod does not meet the homogeneity assumption, would a GLM be okay to use in this case as well?
2) Does the p-value for the interaction term indicate if the slopes are different? So a higher p-value would then signify no difference between them? 
I apologize for all the questions